# Bind WPF DataGrid to ListItemCollection

Tags: client-object-model

I need to display the items from a list in WPF application. 
I have WPF DataGrid and I use managed client object model to retreive the list items.
I would appreciate if someone can explain a way to bind the DataGrid to the ListItemCollection and show the item fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer. 
The DataGrid column bindings should look something like this:

```
   clientDataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
   {
       Binding = new Binding("FieldValues[Title]"),
       Header = "Title"
   });
```